# How might clouds be produced in a large underground fantasy realm?

Tags: science-based, weather, underground, clouds

I'm attempting to give my fantasy world weather/clouds, (some might be light-producing to add to other light sources, so if there's a scientific way to do that, please give it to me). There are multiple waterfalls and waterways, most of which are saltwater due to the fact that the water comes from the ocean (flooding doesn't happen because magic).  So would it function normally or would something need to be different?

Comment: If someone wants to do the math and claim the points, any large enough open chamber will have the capabilities of having clouds and weather. The key will be a temperature differential with altitude.

Comment: In the real world, the [Vertical Assembly Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Assembly_Building) used by NASA to assemble the large pre-manufactured space vehicle components, such as the massive Saturn V and the Space Shuttle is so large that *"it has its own weather, including rain clouds forming below the ceiling on very humid days"* (Wikipedia, quoting NASA). The VAB is 526 ft (160.3 meters)  tall, with an interior volume of 129,428,000 cubic feet (3,665,000 m³).

Comment: The moment you said *"because magic"* you've answered yourself.

Comment: There were clouds and rain inside space shuttle hangar. With large enough space, it seems that preventing clouds is harder than making them.

Comment: There are  also clouds and rain in other large buildings such as the airship hangars in Cardington Bedfordshire ( that were used in the filming of the Nolan Batman movies) and in similar hangars fro airships in America as Molot and AlexP say it can happen quite naturally.

Comment: there are some caves that have their own weather systems, like er wang dong in china. this i believe was due to the supermassive size of the cave, allowing humidity from the ground rising into the cooler air near the roof of the cavern, where it forms clouds. since flooding doesn't happen (because magic, as you said), this process could go on without risk of the water level rising and threatening the residents, therefore creating an underground pocket with its own weather system.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer may be as simple as having a [Water Cycle](https://pmm.nasa.gov/education/water-cycle).  That is, evaporation and transpiration (evaporation from plants), leading to condensation (clouds), leading to precipitation, then runoff and pooling, leading back to evaporation...

You can't get much more realistic than mimicking nature.  So if you have water and plants in a warm climate, clouds and rain are probably a given.

You might want to seriously consider the "heat source".  The Sun is a reliable, giant nuclear reactor.  Having a reliable heat source for evaporation could be important (like geothermal pool or high temperature rocks -- the Earth's core is also a reactor).

If you prefer a "fantasy" source, you could:

1. Have creatures that release a cloud-like gas.
2. Have pillars from underground releasing the clouds (where you don't know the source, but it always comes from the same place).
3. Have two substances interact to form clouds, like a big bang.
4. Have a cloud spirit/elemental.

And, alternatively, you could just add them to your realm without an explanation.  Sometimes leaving mysteries charges the imagination of others.

Comment: Any large enclosed space with sufficient moisture and temperature gradients will develop clouds. For example, the space shuttle hanger.